# Commerce stock rule creation

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce, rules

I'm trying to create a rule that will unpublish a product display only if it's a certain type of product once stock reaches zero.
I can't seem to find any good recipes to do that. I don't know anything about the inner workings of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and everything I've blindly tried doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Commerce Stock (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock)?

Comment: Yes, using Commerce Stock.

Comment: I found this link, but I think it's outdated as I can't find any field_product_reference to build my view with. Can anyone suggest an update on the build here?

[link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1345216#comment-8306801)

Comment: Do your product display nodes have a product reference on them? Nearly all commerce tools assume that's how it is setup. If not, how do you plan to determine which node to unpublish when the stock count hits zero?

Comment: They're standard commerce products, if it adds a product reference by default then it must have one. I don't know enough to turn off something like that.
I made my product type by cloning an existing product and duplicating every field it had.